# how to generate more "gusts" of wind with the wind force field?

Tags: physics

the noise amount is on max but i'm still not able to get the quick short random bursts of wind i'm looking for. is there a way to increase this amount or a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Another way to do this would be to use a noise modifier on the f-curve of the strength value. Like he does in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dusm_fQekww&ab_channel=TheWPGuru), but do it with the strength value instead of x/y location.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've already thought about that but you could simply keyframe the *Strength* value of your wind, going, for example, from 100 to 1000 or whatever, then use the NLA to repeat this as a cycle. It looks like creating a *Noise* modifier in the *Graph Editor* doesn't have any influence though...

[image]